# Как раскрыть фильтр по нажатию на блок?

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce

Использую плагин *WooCommerce Product Filter - WOOF*.

Сейчас, чтоб открыть фильтр `"Пол - "` нужно нажать на `" - "`, а я бы хотел, чтоб он открывался при клике на весь блок.

Знаю, что надо менять что-то в каком то файле, но найти не могу. Возможно, тут есть люди, которые сталкивались с этим плагином.

Скрин фильтров:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Стилями не пробовали сделать значок блочным?

Comment: мне нужно чтобы на весь блок,при нажатие открывался фильтр.То есть,даже если на слово "Пол" например.Поэтому нужно в коде менять ссылку,а я хз что за файл и где :С

Comment: Так я вам предлагаю + сделать блоком! Он растянется на всю ширину и перекроет собой слово "пол": `display: block; width: 100%; text-align: right`. Ссылку дайте посмотреть

Comment: @mihdan
http://tiarsekj.bget.ru/shop/ Вот тут Слова заданы заголовками(h4).Тоесть при вашем решении,оно опускается
Идет заголовок,потом снизу этот блок

Comment: @mihdan Легче найти файл,который отвечает за верстку и вставить просто в этот блок ссылку,а отсюда убрать.Но где этот файл я не знаю :С

Comment: Коцать плагин - не решение проблемы, а костыль

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно добавить в свою тему стили примерно как на скриншоте (красный фон для наглядности):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: <img src="https://pp.vk.me/c636728/v636728194/38dfa/XUbdvA_AnYU.jpg" width="100" height="100">

Comment: пля, крч у меня полоска на весь экран растягивается http://s013.radikal.ru/i322/1610/4b/53ba0e30c54d.jpg

Comment: Для h4 надо position: relative; на моем скрине видно

Comment: Все,точно спасибо большое,выручил)